# How do you implement something like a static method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

While I was looking through the documentation for `String`, referencing `String.fromCharCode`.  I noticed that it was different from the majority of the other `String` methods in the way that it didn't have a `.prototype` before the method, Ex. `String.prototype.CharCodeAt`.  I assume that it must be similar to that of a static reference in java given that it's usage requires you to reference the `String` class/Object, Ex.

```
var str = "foo";
var code = str.charCodeAt(0);
var character = String.fromCharCode(code); // This is the reference I'm talking about
alert(code); // Output: 102
alert(character); // Output: f
```

My question is how would you implement a method so that it is accessed in the same style as `String.fromCharCode` in your own code?

Comment: Funny enough I've already read through a lot of that trying to find an answer to this question and was unsuccessful.  It is possible I just missed it somehow, is there a specific section I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects. It makes it possible to assign method property directly to it, which would behave as static method:

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.static = function() { ... }
```

Just like you would expect.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't seem to find.

Answer (score 0):

[DZone's](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/object-oriented-javascript) ref card provides a great reference for the Object-oriented javascript, I highly recommend it. The related paragraphs

> There is no direct support for static members. Constructor functions
>   are used to create static members. Static members can’t be accessed
>   with “this” keyword.

**private static members**

```
   function Factory(){}
    // public static method
    Factory.getType = function (){
      return “Object Factory”;
    };

    // public static field
    Factory.versionId = “F2.0”;
    Factory.prototype.test = function(){
      console.log(this.versionId); // undefined
      console.log(Factory.versionId); // F2.0
      console.log(Factory.getType()); // Object Factory
    }
    var factory = new Factory();
    factory.test();
```

**public static members**

```
var Book = (function () {
// private static field
    var numOfBooks = 0;
// private static method
    function checkIsbn(isbn) {
        if (isbn.length != 10 && isbn.length != 13)
            throw new Error(“isbn is not valid!”);
    }

    function Book(isbn, title) {
        checkIsbn(isbn);
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        numOfBooks++;
        this.getNumOfBooks = function () {
            return numOfBooks;
        }
    }

    return Book;
})();
var firstBook = new Book(“0-943396-04-2”, “First Title”);
console.log(firstBook.title); // First Title
console.log(firstBook.getNumOfBooks()); // 1
var secondBook = new Book(“0-85131-041-9”, “Second Title”);
console.log(firstBook.title); // First Title
console.log(secondBook.title); // Second Title
console.log(firstBook.getNumOfBooks()); // 2
console.log(secondBook.getNumOfBooks()); // 2
```